# Clickhouse Unable to attach part because of file permission

Tags: backup, olap, clickhouse

I'm having some problem backing up partitions and loading them to another instance.

I've done the following

```sql
ALTER TABLE Test FREEZE PARTITION 201912
```

took the generated partition from shadow and moved it to another instance under detached folder , 
and then ran 
`ALTER TABLE Test ATTACH PARTITION 201912`

and it failed for  "Access to file denied /....attaching_2019../

which is odd because I set the entire lib with 777 permission and it's happening , any idea?

attaching the error

```sh
2019.12.16 08:28:55.541817 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> executeQuery: (from [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:47426) ALTER TABLE test ATTACH PARTITION 201912
2019.12.16 08:28:55.541967 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> default.test: Looking for parts for partition 201912 in detached/
2019.12.16 08:28:55.542005 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> default.test: Found part 201912_0_1_1
2019.12.16 08:28:55.542020 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> default.test: 1 of them are active
2019.12.16 08:28:55.542053 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> default.test: Checking parts
2019.12.16 08:28:55.542061 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> default.test: Checking part attaching_201912_0_1_1
2019.12.16 08:28:55.543951 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Trace> default.test: Renaming temporary part detached/attaching_201912_0_1_1 to 201912_6_6_0.
2019.12.16 08:28:55.544832 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (total): 0.00 B.
2019.12.16 08:28:55.544864 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Error> executeQuery: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 1, e.displayText() = Access to file denied: insufficient permissions: /data/clickhouse/data/data/default/test/detached/attaching_201912_0_1_1 (version 19.16.3.6 (official build) (from [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:47426) (in query: ALTER TABLE test ATTACH PARTITION 201912 )
2019.12.16 08:28:55.544954 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (for query): 0.00 B.
2019.12.16 08:28:55.544972 [ 65 ] {b62d9630-7ab2-48a4-89a5-47d296151802} <Information> TCPHandler: Processed in 0.003 sec
```

Comment: could you call *ls -lh* command in this folder to make sure that moved partition has the same permissions, user and group as attached partitions?

Answer (score 3):

```
chown -R clickhouse  /var/lib/clickhouse
```

This fixed the issue for me